Balanced coloring for $\mathbb{Z}^n$ with $m$ colors
Call a coloring using $m$ colors on a finite number of points in $\mathbb{Z}^n$ balanced if for any line parallel to one of $n$ axes, the difference between the number of points for any 2 colors is at most 1.
Does such a coloring exist for all $m, n \ge  2$?
Note that this problem is a generalization for IMO 1986 problem 6 where $m = n = 2$. I solved the original problem using induction on the number of points by removing one that lies on a line with an odd number of points and tackle the case when all lines have an even number of points by considering the simple graph with vertices as the horizontal and vertical lines that contain at least one point, which are finitely many, edges as the mentioned integer points connecting a horizontal and vertical line sharing one and use the fact that this graph is Eulerian to color the edges so that two adjacent edges in the cycle are colored differently. I have tried to create a similar reasoning when $m > 2$ or $n > 2$ but failed.
I would appreciate any improvement to my method or a solution to the above problem even if it’s just the case $m = 2$ or $n = 2$.

When $n \ge 3$, such a coloring does not necessarily exist. First, here is a counterexample in $\mathbb Z^3$ when $m=2$:

We should think of this counterexample as consisting of three $L$ shapes strung together. A $L$ shape is a configuration
A
|
|
X---B

which forces points $A$ and $B$ to have the same color. The diagram above has one of these in the plane $x=0$, one in the plane $z=0$, and one in the plane $x=1$, resulting in $\operatorname{color}(0,0,1) = \operatorname{color}(0,1,0) = \operatorname{color} (1,2,0) = \operatorname{color}(1,0,1)$. But the final two points are collinear and so no valid coloring can give them the same color.
For $m\ge 3$ and $n \ge 3$, we can find a counterexample by generalizing the one above. Instead of the L-shaped gadget, use the following (illustrated for $m=5$):
A
|
*--*--*--*--*
|  |  |  |  |
*--*--*--*--*
|  |  |  |  |
*--*--*--*--*
|  |  |  |  |
*--*--*--*--*
   |  |  |  |
   *--*--*--*--B

Suppose point $A$ gets color $c$. Then the $m-1$ points directly below it cannot reuse color $c$, but they are each on a horizontal line of $m$ points that must use color $c$ at least once. Therefore the $(m-1)\times(m-1)$ grid of points to their right must contain $m-1$ points with color $c$: one in each row, and hence one in each column. This means that every vertical line in that grid already includes color $c$, so their bottom point cannot have color $c$. Finally, the horizontal line containing $B$ must have a point of color $c$, and the only point that can have this color is point $B$ itself.
Here is an illustration (again, for $m=5$) of how this gadget can be used to get a counterexample:


On the other hand, when $n=2$, such a coloring exists for all $n$. (This is essentially my strategy here, but generalized to $m$ colors and somewhat simplified.)
Let $P$ be our set of points; assume without loss of generality that $P \subseteq \{1,2,\dots,N\}^2$ for some integer $N$. We first modify the problem in two ways:

We replace $P$ by a larger point set $Q$ containing $m^2$ copies of $P$: the sets $(aN,bN) + P$, where $0 \le a,b \le m-1$.
After this operation, a horizontal or vertical line containing $k$ points in $P$ contains $km$ points in $Q$. We split every such line into $k$ segments, each containing $m$ consecutive points of that line. (This includes horizontal and vertical lines containing $1$ point in $P$; they contain $m$ points in $Q$, which we end up turning into just one segment. As a result, every point in $Q$ is on some horizontal and some vertical segment.)

Our goal is now to color so that all $m$ points on a segment get different colors.
If we solve this new coloring problem, then the copy of $P$ inside $Q$ is also correctly colored. A $k$-point horizontal or vertical line inside $P$ ends up being divided into $\lfloor km\rfloor$ complete segments and maybe a partial segment: so in the coloring of $Q$, all colors must get used $\lfloor km\rfloor$ times on the complete segments, and some may be used an additional time on the partial segment.
On to solving the problem for $Q$. We consider the bipartite graph $G$ with the horizontal segments in $Q$ on one side and the vertical segments in $Q$ on the other side; for each point in $Q$, we draw an edge between the horizontal and vertical segment containing it. The graph $G$ is $m$-regular, and by a theorem of Kőnig, we can partition it into $m$ perfect matchings. (Briefly: we can apply Hall's theorem to get a perfect matching in any regular graph, then we can remove the edges of that perfect matching and repeat.)
This partition into $m$ perfect matchings is exactly the coloring we want: for  each $i=1,\dots,m$, take the $i^{\text{th}}$ perfect matching in $G$ and use the $i^{\text{th}}$ color on all points in $Q$ corresponding to its edges. Every segment corresponds to a vertex in $G$, which is incident to exactly one edge of the $i^{\text{th}}$ matching; therefore the segment contains exactly one point of the $i^{\text{th}}$ color.
